# adding new values to dictionary with a list as its value

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have a dictionary like this :

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> StudentsByTeacherName = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

this dictionary is inside a loop i want the dictionary Value for a specific key get updated in each loop. if there are no new keys there to add to the dictionary

```
foreach (var item5 in StudentsByTeacherName)
                {
                    if (StudentsByTeacherName.ContainsKey(item5.Key))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StudentsByTeacherName.Add(item4.Value,StudentName);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: List<string> abc = StudentsByTeacherName["item3.Key"];
                abc.Add("def");

Comment: Are you sure you have to build this up yourself? You may be better off using a lookup: `var lookup = students.ToLookup(s => s.TeacherName);`

Comment: Your if check does not make sense. StudentsByTeacherName will always contain the key from item5.Key because item5 is a key/value pair from StudentsByTeacherName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want the dictionary Value for a specific key get updated in each
>   loop. if there are no new keys there to add to the dictionary

For that instead of checking for `ContainsKey` simply do:

```
TeacherName[item3.Key] = yourStringList;
```

The indexer `[]` will update the existing Key and inserts if the key doesn't exists.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i don`t want the existing keys to get updated. i want to update their values

Comment: The code provided by Habib will either update the *value* or add a new key that contains the value, i.e. it is like an "AddOrUpdate" method. Isn't this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change your property or indexer value since this is read only. What you can do is access it via its index:

```
 foreach (var item5 in StudentsByTeacherName)
    {
      if (StudentsByTeacherName.ContainsKey(item5.Key))
         {
            //This will add new values on your list of string on specific 
            //keys and will not delete the existing ones:

            List<string> list = StudentsByTeacherName[item5.Key];
            list.Add("Your additional value here");
         }
         else
         {
            StudentsByTeacherName.Add(item4.Value,StudentName);
         }
    }
```

This will update the value of string list and not the key itself.

Comment: I think this will delete the previous data  and replace them with new one. i want the new data added to the list. not making a whole new list

Comment: Okay I understand, kindly see my updated code @HossainEhsani

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach (var item5 in StudentsByTeacherName)
{
    if(item5.Value == null)
    {
        item5.Value = new List<String();
    }

    item5.Value[item4.Key] = item4.Value;
}
```

I am assuming that item4 is the Student.  This will replace an existing value or add a new value.